# Unable to read execution data file jacoco.exec

Tags: java, gwt, ant, code-coverage, jacoco

I want to get the code coverage of a GWT application using jacoco. The build is done using ant and the build file looks like this

```
<jacoco:coverage destfile="${local.build.dir}/jacoco.exec">
      <junit printsummary="yes"
             fork="true"
             dir="${basedir}"
             forkmode="@{aij-forkmode}"
             haltonfailure="yes"
             maxmemory="2000m"
             showoutput="no">
        <jvmarg value="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m"/>
        <sysproperty key="gwt.args" value="-prod -gen ${local.build.dir}/gen -war ${local.build.dir}/build/war" if:true="@{aij-prod}"/>
        <sysproperty key="gwt.args" value="-devMode -logLevel WARN -war ${local.build.dir}/build/war" unless:true="@{aij-prod}"/>
        <sysproperty key="java.awt.headless" value="true"/>
        <classpath refid="@{aij-testingtarget}.path"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <!-- If the ant command line sets the test_name property (see above)
             then we just run that one test. -->
        <test fork="true" name="${test_name}" todir="${reports.dir}/raw/" if="test_name"/>
        <!-- otherwise, we run all the tests -->
        <batchtest fork="true" todir="${reports.dir}/raw/" unless="test_name">
          <fileset dir="${tests.dir}">
            <include name="@{aij-dir}/**/*Test.java" />
            <exclude name="@{aij-dir}/**/Abstract*Test.java" />
          </fileset>
        </batchtest>
      </junit>
      </jacoco:coverage>
      
      <junitreport todir="${reports.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${reports.dir}/raw/">
          <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${reports.dir}/html"/>
      </junitreport>
      
      <jacoco:report>
        <executiondata>
          <file file="${build.dir}/jacoco.exec"/>
        </executiondata>
        <structure name="Example Project">
          <classfiles>
               <fileset dir="${class.dir}"/>
          </classfiles>
          <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
               <fileset dir="${src.dir}"/>
          </sourcefiles>
        </structure>

          <html destdir="${coverage.dir}"/>
      </jacoco:report>
```

I am getting the following error when I run tests command `Unable to read execution data file /build/jacoco.exec` for the jacoco report task.
How can I solve this error.

I tried different stackoverflow answers but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jacoco:coverage` task specifies

```
destfile="${local.build.dir}/jacoco.exec"
```

whereas your `jacoco:report` task specifies

```
        <executiondata>
          <file file="${build.dir}/jacoco.exec"/>
```

so I guess that change of the last one on

```
        <executiondata>
          <file file="${local.build.dir}/jacoco.exec"/>
```

should help.

Comment: Thanks, @Godin for the help. I am facing one more issue. "Source file "com/google/appinventor/client/OdeTest.java" was not found during generation of report." let's suppose src has client, server and shared sub folders then for server and shared we can see the lines which are covered only for the client folder files I am getting this error. Your help will be appreciated!